# OWASP ZAP Github action attack strength of full scan

Tags: github-actions, owasp, zap

Is it somehow possible to change the attack strength of the OWASP ZAP full scan?
I use the advanced github action method like here descripted
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/owasp-zap-full-scan.

It's necessary for us to reduce the attack strength to "low".

To avoid this type of anwers:
-No, it's not an option to use the "baseline" variant.

Anyway, I realy hope someone can help me, because the documentation is not given any answers

Answer (score 0):

The packaged scan (which the action is based on) are meant to be fairly "point and shoot"ish. If you need to customize things more then your best bet is to look at other ZAP automation options.

The options and documentation are available here:
https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/

If you want something more than the packaged scans/actions. Then you're essentially down to the [Automation Framework](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/automation-framework/) and running ZAP in daemon mode then "driving" it via the [API](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#introduction) however you like.

Comment: To follow on from what kingthorin said, we are planning on releasing a GitHub action which supports the Automation Framework, but no ETA yet..